# PowerShell script to check if MMS is connected to Web Application

Tags: powershell, managed-metadata, web-application

I want to check if Managed Metadata Service is connected to any Web Application by powershell script. What will be the possible script to check this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My VM are down so that i cant right the script but i can give you an idea.

> Whenever you create a new Service Application in Central
>   Administration, this new service application will automatically be
>   added to this “ Default Proxy Group”. When you create a new service
>   application via PowerShell, the new service application will NOT
>   automatically be assigned to the Default or any other Proxy group.

Here are the steps:

1. Get available Proxy groups in your SharePoint 2013 Farm Get‐SPServiceApplicationProxyGroup
2. Now check the member of each proxy group. `Get‐SPServiceApplicationProxyGroup | Format‐Table ‐wrap`
3. if you have only one Prxoy group(default) and MMS part of it then that;s it.

   --This Will give you list of all proxies aviable in the farm
   Get‐SPServiceApplicationProxyGroup | Format‐Table ‐wrap

   --get the Web application 
   $web = Get-SPWebApplication http://Url of WEb application

   --this will tell which proxy it is connected and what services applications
   $web.ServiceApplicationProxyGroup | Format‐Table ‐wrap

Comment: Need Powershell script to fully understand! Hopefully your VM will be up now.

Comment: check theupdated answer

Comment: Thats fine, I want to check for all web applications in the Farm if they are connected to newly created MMS, How i can check for all web applications?